# Why values are disappearing?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am working in Odoo13 I am calculating some taxes while creating my sale order and while doing this I am successfully calculating my respective taxes as following.

[image]

But after saving my sale order or by confirming it all my custom tax fields disappear like:

[image]

**Here is my Python File code:**

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
_inherit = ['sale.order']

federal_tax = fields.Float('Federal Tax', readonly=True)
state_tax = fields.Float('State Tax', readonly=True)
county_tax = fields.Float('County Tax', readonly=True)
city_tax = fields.Float('City Tax', readonly=True)
unincorporated_tax = fields.Float('Unincorporated Tax', store=True, readonly=True)
```

**And here is my XML File:**

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page/group/group/field[@name='amount_untaxed']" position="after">
    <field name="federal_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('federal_tax','==', 0.00)]}"/>
    <field name="state_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('state_tax','==', 0.00)]}"/>
    <field name="county_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('county_tax','==', 0.00)]}"/>
    <field name="city_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('city_tax','==', 0.00)]}"/>
    <field name="unincorporated_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('unincorporated_tax','==', 0.00)]}"/>
</xpath>
```

> Note: After confirming my order or by saving it my custom fields
>   value turn to 0 that is why they are disappearing but why they are
>   turning to zero?

Comment: @CharifDZ there?

Comment: Adam,  Are you computing these field by an onchage method, And why are they readonly if they are computed fields you should add the compute attribute to tell Odoo how they should be computed. And to answer why are not saved it's because they are readonly in the UI and Odoo by default ignore thus fields when calling create method , if you debug values parametre  you will not find these field in the dictionary because they where not send by the client side. Now to fix this first tell me are these fields computed or they can be changed and why you did not declare them as computed fields

Comment: I think starting from Odoo 11, Odoo provide a special attribute to force sending readonly field wighout having to install readonlybypass app. I think it's `force_save="1"` but I don't think it's enough because what if the record was saved by an another App using Odoo API if they forgot to pass the value yhey will not be computed by the onchange method because it's called only by Odoo UI.

Comment: @CharifDZ i am using force_save="1" it is working for me but when I shift from sale order to invoice same issue by clicking create invoice button same issue

Comment: Yes I told you Odoo by default doesn't send these fiels frol the UI and why you are nor defining compute attribute of these fields? Are they always computed

Comment: yes...If i make them compute field problem will be solved?

Comment: Yes because compute field are computed when create and write call are triggered, of curse make sure you specify the right dependencie. Non computed field must be passed in the dictionary but computed field are automatically computed if one of there depends fields are changed. I hope You got the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put readonly field attribute on view instead of model, for example:

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
_inherit = ['sale.order']

    federal_tax = fields.Float('Federal Tax',) 
    state_tax = fields.Float('State Tax',) 
    county_tax = fields.Float('County Tax',) 
    city_tax = fields.Float('City Tax',) 
    unincorporated_tax = fields.Float('Unincorporated Tax',)


<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page/group/group/field[@name='amount_untaxed']" position="after">
    <field name="federal_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('federal_tax','==', 0.00)]}" readonly="True"/>
    <field name="state_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('state_tax','==', 0.00)]}" readonly="True"/>
    <field name="county_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('county_tax','==', 0.00)]}" readonly="True"/>
    <field name="city_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('city_tax','==', 0.00)]}" readonly="True"/>
    <field name="unincorporated_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('unincorporated_tax','==', 0.00)]}" readonly="True"/> 
</xpath>
```

Now the main question, why your data is not being stored, it is because on the model definition you defined the fields as readonly, by default Odoo doesn't store form data from fields for which `readonly` attribute is set to `True`. I am assuming that you are calculating those readonly fields on the form view from `onchange` function, so the data is only calculated on the fly, but not yet saved on database, but as this are readonly, Odoo is ignoring those fields value and hence you are always getting ) even after pressing save. You can override the Odoo default behavior using `force_save` attribute, which overrides Odoo default form behavior to submit fields value even if readonly.

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page/group/group/field[@name='amount_untaxed']" position="after">
    <field name="federal_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('federal_tax','==', 0.00)]}" readonly="True" force_save="1"/>
    <field name="state_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('state_tax','==', 0.00)]}" readonly="True" force_save="1"/>
    <field name="county_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('county_tax','==', 0.00)]}" readonly="True" force_save="1"/>
    <field name="city_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('city_tax','==', 0.00)]}" readonly="True" force_save="1"/>
    <field name="unincorporated_tax" attrs="{'invisible':[('unincorporated_tax','==', 0.00)]}" readonly="True" force_save="1"/> 
</xpath>
```

Odoo follows same behavior for `invisible` fields also, so you have to use `force_save` attribute in `invisible` fields also.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `invisible` attribute from xml field declaration.

Restart Odoo server, upgrade module. And verify your output.

Afterwards, you will know where is problem.

If you want to hide tax, then do following.

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('federal_tax','=', 0.00)]}"
```

NOTE:

I haven't seen any tax fields calculation and you have declared it with `readonly=True` attributes. That's means it will flush value at that time of record save.